# What's a "Cheap" way to check if WebGL is supported in a browser? (using JS)

Tags: javascript, webgl

As far as I could find, `probablySupportsContext` is no longer supported in Canvas API, and running `!!canvas.getContext('webgl')` is, at least as far as I know, very expensive and slow.

What's the best and least performance-consuming way of telling wether WebGL is supported in a client using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

I would imagine the way a popular library like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) does it would be performance-minded. They use `supportsContext` when `probablySupportsContext` is not available and check if those are supported in a canvas element, otherwise they look for a `WebGlRenderingContext` in the `window` object.

In their source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/webgl.js

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var supports = 'probablySupportsContext' in canvas
    ? 'probablySupportsContext'
    :  'supportsContext';


if (supports in canvas) {
  return canvas[supports]('webgl') || canvas[supports]('experimental-webgl');
}

return 'WebGLRenderingContext' in window;
```

I don't believe there are any other ways to detect this feature other than going down the path of creating the context as you've already shown.

Comment: Hey there, thanks, but I already looked at Modernizr's code, and it was not helpful, as `supportsContext` doesn't seems to be supported (at least in Chrome and Safari), and `WebGLRenderingContext` exists in `window` even when WebGL is not supported.

Comment: Are Safari and Chrome the only browsers you're having trouble with? Do you know which versions?

Comment: I want a solution for all modern browsers, and it seems like `probablySupportsContext` and `supportsContext` are not supported in any one of them. See browser compatibility in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: See the browser compatibility table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API   Chrome and Safari have had support for a long time, so I'm not sure which versions you're testing that say there is a context even when WebGL not supported, unless the client's GPU does not support it, in which case I believe the method you've listed is the only possible way to determine that. In my tests, it only took 20-30ms to use `getContext()`, which is not great, but hardly something I would say say is a performance show-stopper. It's also how advanced features are detected in Modernizr